# Erasing element in vector with < n complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to erase an element from sorted vector while restraining from complexity which is equal or more than n. I know about `vector . erase` method which will erase it but the complexity of it is n. I could just rewrite that structure element with the last element and then use popback to remove the last method which should be constant but the problem is that it won't stay sorted so i would have to sort it again. Is it even possible to solve this problem and stay below n complexity ?

Comment: Can't do. Either a.) use another data structure b.) remove elements in bulk (see erase-remove idiom) c.) mark the elements as unused somehow

Comment: Marking element as unused somehow is not the right option for me it would eat lots of memory.

Comment: Before you attempt any changes, make sure that you **measure the performance**. On modern hardware, it often takes surprisingly large N for the vector to be outperformed by other container types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need it sorted, there is no solution in `std::vector` (as far as I know). However, `std::vector` does not seem to be the right container for your case. `std::list` is one option for you (there could be better).

from this reference :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/

> **Complexity**
>
> Linear in the number of elements erased (destruction).

Which is mean it would call the destructor N times which N is the number of items to be deleted. So, it is linear in the number of deleted items (not the `std::list` items count)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

if you have to keep your data structure sorted, and be able to erase element(s) from the middle with high performance, aint it better to replace vector by another container (set, multiset for example)?.

Comment: @kvway using a set/multiset is probably what you need, because with a list you has O(n) cost oof accessing one element.